# how do i check whether a number contains all the digits of another number?

Tags: c#

i'm trying to do something where I have *two numbers* (let's say `123` and `5321`). And I want to check if the second number contains all the digits of the first number. now if there is any way this could be done using if and for loops that would help me so much but ANY HELP IS GREATLY APPRECIATED! oh, and and it doesn't matter how many of the same digits a number has(33 and 503 still counts)

Comment: Convert the numbers to string. Treat the other string as a character array. Profit.

Answer (score 2):

If we *don't count* number of digits (e.g. `22` appears in `123` even if `22` has *two* `2` when `123` has just one `2`):

```
 int first = 123;
 int second = 5321;

 // If second contains first 
 bool contains = !first
   .ToString()
   .Except(second.ToString())
   .Any();
```

If number of digits matters (i.e. `22` doesn't appear in `123`):

```
  var dict = second
    .ToString()
    .GroupBy(d => d)
    .ToDictionary(chunk => chunk.Key, 
                  chunk => chunk.Count());

  // If second contains first 
  bool contains = first
    .ToString()
    .GroupBy(d => d)
    .All(chunk => dict.TryGetValue(chunk.Key, out var count) && count >= chunk.Count());
```

**Edit:** good old `if` and `for` loop solution:

```
  string firstSt = first.ToString();
  string secondSt = second.ToString();

  // contains unless we find a counter example
  bool contains = true;

  for (int i = 0; i < firstSt.Length; ++i) {
    char toFind = firstSt[i];
    bool found = false; 

    for (int j = 0; j < secondSt.Length; ++j) {
      if (toFind = secondSt[j]) {
        found = true;

        break;
      } 
    }  

    //  firstSt[i] is not found within secondSt
    if (!found) {
      contains = false;

      break;
    } 
  }
```

Comment: thank you so much! may i ask if there is any way this can be done with if and for loops?

Answer (score 1):

Approach with `string` and `Contains()`

```
int i1 = 5321, i2 = 123;
bool result = i1.ToString().All(i2.ToString().Contains); //false, 5 missing
```